# Avoid module update

Tags: magento2, module, upgrade

I've overrided an open-source module downloaded on GitHub.

I change some things in mainly in views, but I don't want theses to do erase if the module is going to be updated.

How can I avoid this ?

Comment: can you explain clearly

Comment: I have downloaded an open source module. I change some part of the code, and I don't want my changes to be removed during the update of the module (the update of the creator of the module)

Comment: which page your modified. if it is model or controller or helper then use override the file using di.xml file

Comment: Mainly views, but also controller

Comment: add this in module.xml <sequence><module name="Namespace_modulename"/></sequence> override the controller and view pages(templates or layouts)

Comment: What is <sequence> supposed to do ?

Answer (score 0):

In your case you should not overwrite existing module, but you should write your own module which extends a github-module functionality and which depends on github-module specific version. In this case, you can be sure that everything will be fine.

In your module you can use a `<sequence>` tag in the `etc/module.xml` configuration file, like:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Your_Module" setup_version="0.0.1">
        <sequence>
            <module name="GitHub_Module"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

This will prevent system loading in case when github-module will be deleted or disabled without disabling your own module.

You can use the `composer.json` configuration file (of your module) to declare a dependency:

```
{
    "name": "yourname/your-module",
    "require": {
        "vendorname/github-module-name" : ">=100.1.0"
    }
    //...
}
```

but this will work only in case when all modules would be installing through composer.